# Implementing DI in a particular situation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to implement DI in a class, but I'm not sure that my design is appropriate.

The relevent code in the class I want to add DI to

```
class DoerValidation 
{
   public DoerValidation()
   {
       compileData();
   }

   private void compileData()
   {
       doersActive = Doer.GetActiveDoers();
       //...
   }
}
```

And in my `Doer` class

```
public partial class Doer
{
   private static readonly DoerRepository repository = new DoerRepository();

   public static IEnumerable<Doer> GetActiveDoers()
   {
       return repository.Doers.Where(c => c.Person.IsActive);
   }
}
```

I just don't get how I could implement DI in this situation. Maybe the `GetActiveDoers` method is bad design? Where would you put this method otherwise?

Would it be a good practice to start adding new methods directly in the repository? Some people told me it should stay clean so it implements only this

```
public interface IDoerRepository
{
    IQueryable<Doer> Doers { get; }
    void SaveDoer(Doer doer);
    void DeleteDoer(Doer doer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to inject the `DoerRepository` into `DoerValidation` basically - pass it into the constructor.

Both the `GetActiveDoers` and the static variable go against the principles of DI, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you expand a little on what would go with the principle in this case?

Comment: +1 for the "against principles of DI".  Could not agree more.

Comment: @Mathieu: `DoerValidation` depends on a `DoerRepository`, effectively: so inject it by passing it into the constructor. Put `GetActiveDoers` onto `DoerRepository` itself as an instance method, or possibly make it an extension method if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods and properties are procedural in nature.  If you expose your GetActiveDoers() method statically, there is no way to inject its functionality -- clients can only ignore it or use it inline wherever it's needed.

If you're committed to DI and to a static implementation, you need to write an instance wrapper for that static class and inject the instance wrapper.